# spatialDistribution()-Operator and non-scalar gradients in Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using the spatialDistribution() Operator in Dymola and get the follwing message when using Hidden.PrintFailureToDifferentiate = true;

"Can only compute non-scalar gradients of functions specifying derivatives and not for: spatialDistribution"

I call the operator like this :

(time_rev,time_flow) = spatialDistribution(time,time,x/length,v_water>=0,{0.0,1.0}, {time,time});

and use it to calculate the outlet Temperature of my pipe.

Anyone got an idea where the issue lies? I don't really understand the error message.

More complete example:

```
cp_in = //Calculates specific Heatcap 
cp_out = //Calculates specific Heatcap 
cp = (cp_in+cp_out)*0.5;
C = (Modelica.Constants.pi*(1/4))*diameter_i^2*fluidInlet.d*cp;
R= // Calculates Heatresistance 
//---------Conservation of mass flow and composition
//The usual stuff equal massflow,xi and p at both connectors
//----------Spatial
tau_nom = C*R;
v_water = //Calc Speed of water from Geometric data and inlet rho
der(x) = v_water;
(time_reversed,time_flow) = spatialDistribution(time,time,x/length,v_water>=0, {0.0,1.0}, {time,time});
 tau_delay= time - time_flow;
 tau_reversed= time - time_reversed; //Not used right now
if inlet.m_flow >= 0 then
  T_out = (T_amb + (T_in - heat.T)*exp(-tau_delay/tau_nom));
  heat.Q_flow = -inlet.m_flow*cp*(T_in - T_out);
  inlet.h = inStream(outlet.h);
else
  outlet.h = inStream(inlet.h);
  T_in = T_out;
  heat.Q_flow = -inlet.m_flow*cp*(T_in - T_out);
end if;
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? I also assume there is some other issue; if you merely cannot compute a gradient it would be a minor issue.

Comment: Added a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for getting this error message is that Dymola cannot compute a gradient, that is likely used as part of computing a Jacobian for a non-linear system of equations.

If you look at the translation log I would expect that "Number of numerical Jacobians: " is non-zero.

A missing Jacobian for a non-linear system of equations is normally not a major issue.

However, that the non-linear system needs the gradient for spatialDistribution does not seem right, since it indicates that the delayed variables are implicitly given in some odd way.

It could be that the delay of the spatial distribution should solve that and in that case Dymola 2019 FD01 might remove the issue if you set Advanced.BreakDelayLoops=true; (but it is difficult to say without the complete model).
(It seems you have an earlier version, and the flag does not work there.)

I know it is a bit late answer, but it was difficult to investigate without a complete model.